# Issues with ASP>NET devexpress grid height

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I am using a devexpress gridview with editform template. My issue is I have many rows within a grid, so when I edit rows at the bottom of a page, the edit form goes below the screen and I have to scroll down to see the whole edit form. Is there a way to set this grid to auto height so I dont have to scroll down. Also the vertical scroll bar is always displayed even if I make it false.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PopUpEditForm So That You Dont have To ScrollDown On The Screen And It appears in the middle of the screen itself.

You can use the following settings for the PopupEditForm for your grid

```
<SettingsEditing EditFormColumnCount="2" Mode="PopupEditForm" PopupEditFormWidth="800px"
PopupEditFormHeight="320px" PopupEditFormVerticalAlign="Below" PopupEditFormHorizontalAlign="Center"
PopupEditFormAllowResize="false" />
```

PopupEditFormWidth,PopupEditFormHeight - You can change it to any size you want so that all your controls are properly placed.

Comment: The popup form is definitely the way to go on this one.